# Placing an if else statement in an mbmenu array

Tags: php, yii

I have the following in a MBMenu bar.

```
array('label'=>'Tab1',
           'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'A', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'A')),
            array('label'=>'B', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'B')),
            array('label'=>'C', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'C')),
)),
```

My goal is place an if statement for the dropdown menu bar of Tab1.

```
array(if(x==1){'label'=>'Tab1'}else{'label'=>'Tab2'},
           'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'A', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'A')),
            array('label'=>'B', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'B')),
            array('label'=>'C', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'C')),
)),
```

Comment: try using ternary `(x==1)? 'label'=>'Tab1 ': 'label'=>'Tab2'`

Answer (score 2):

Can't you do this:

```
if(x==1){
   $label = "Tab1";
} else {
   $label = "Tab2";
}
    array('label'=>$label,
               'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'A', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'A')),
                array('label'=>'B', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'B')),
                array('label'=>'C', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'C')),
    )),
```